# Как изменить обработчик события на время выполнения post запроса?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php

Имеется кнопка:

```
<a id="more-button" href="http://debian.host/services/entries" data-value="4" data-count="1">Показать еще...</a>
```

С помощью следующего обработчика я пытаюсь реализовать бесконечную прокрутку ([например, так](http://xozblog.ru/2013/01/infinite-scroll/))

```
    $('#more-button').click(function () {
        var btn = $(this);
        $.post(
            btn.attr('href'),

            // смещение списка записей генерируется динамически, 
            // (data-value генерирует бэк-енд)
            { offset: btn.data('value') * btn.data('count') },

            function( data ) {

                // по загрузке результата выполненного post запроса
                // добавляем его в контейнер
                $('.addable').html($('.addable').html() + data);

                // увеличиваем счетчик смещений
                btn.data('count', btn.data('count') + 1);

                // отключаем кнопку, если загружены все возможные записи
                if($('.entry').size() != $('#more-button').data('value')) 
                    $('#more-button').parents('.wrapper').hide();
            }
        );
        return false;
    });
```

Сейчас это работает правильно, но нужно доработать таким образом, чтобы на время выполнения post запроса кнопка (ссылка) отключалась, была неактивной (изменялся ее обработчик) а после его выполнения возвращалась в прежнее состояние. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно например флаг ставить. В качестве флага можно использовать css-класс, тогда неактивную кнопку можно и оформить как неактивную:

```
$('#more-button').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    if(!btn.hasClass('load')){
        btn.addClass('load')
        $.post(
            btn.attr('href'),

            // смещение списка записей генерируется динамически, 
            // (data-value генерирует бэк-енд)
            { offset: btn.data('value') * btn.data('count') },

            function( data ) {

                // по загрузке результата выполненного post запроса
                // добавляем его в контейнер
                $('.addable').html($('.addable').html() + data);

                // увеличиваем счетчик смещений
                btn.data('count', btn.data('count') + 1);

                // отключаем кнопку, если загружены все возможные записи
                if($('.entry').size() != $('#more-button').data('value')) 
                    $('#more-button').parents('.wrapper').hide();
                btn.removeClass('load')
            }
        );
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ставить какой то флаг действия, например.

```
if (!is_request){
   $.ajax(
   beforeSend:function(){is_request=true;}
   success:function(){is_request=false;}        
   );
}
```